# NumPy's dot product gives two different results depending on array dtype

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have some grayscale image data (0-255). Depending on the NumPy dtype, I am getting different dot product results. For example, `x0` and `x1` are the same image:

```
>>> x0
array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
>>> x1
array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
>>> (x0 == x1).all()
True
>>> np.dot(x0, x1)
133
>>> np.dot(x0.astype(np.float64), x1.astype(np.float64))
6750341.0
```

I know the second dot product is correct because, since they are the same image, the cosine distance should be 0:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance
>>> distance.cosine(x0, x1)
0.99998029729164795
>>> distance.cosine(x0.astype(np.float64), x1.astype(np.float64))
0.0
```

Of course, dot product should work for integers. And for small arrays, it does:

```
>>> v = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> v
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8)
>>> np.dot(v, v)
14
>>> np.dot(v.astype(np.float64), v.astype(np.float64))
14.0
>>> distance.cosine(v, v)
0.0
```

What's happening. Why is the dot product giving me different answers depending on dtype?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The datatype `uint8` is limited to 8 bits, so it can only represent the values 0, 1, ..., 255. Your dot product overflows the available range of values, so only the last 8 bits are kept. Those last 8 bits contain the value 133. You can verify this:

```
6750341 % (2 ** 8) == 133
# True
```

Comment: Thank you! If you're interested, I actually have a follow-up question related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286058